# Max sequence for every sequence SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this data on SQL Server

```
emp_id   date           seq
1        2020-10-01     1
1        2020-10-02     2
1        2020-10-05     1
1        2020-10-06     2
2        2020-10-01     1
2        2020-10-02     2
2        2020-10-03     3
```

I want to transform the data to max row for every sequence like this:

```
emp_id   date           seq
1        2020-10-02     2
1        2020-10-06     2
2        2020-10-03     3
```

I tried using max(seq) but the return only the max sequence for every employee, not for every sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEAD()` window function to get the next value of `seq` of each row and fliter out the rows where the next value of `seq` is greater than the current one:

```
SELECT emp_id, date, seq
FROM (
  SELECT *, LEAD(seq) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY date) next_seq
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE seq > next_seq OR next_seq IS NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=427504b5644f157d43fd1bbfae5b831d).

Results:

| emp_id | date | seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-10-02 | 2 |
| 1 | 2020-10-06 | 2 |
| 2 | 2020-10-03 | 3 |

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is `WITH TIES` in concert with the window function  `dense_rank()`

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties * 
 From  YourTable
 Order By dense_rank() over (partition by emp_id order by seq desc)
```

**Results**

```
emp_id  date        seq
1       2020-10-02  2
1       2020-10-06  2
2       2020-10-03  3
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply filter `DENSE_RANK = 1`

`DENSE_RANK` gives you tied results (same row-number for same order), `ROW_NUMBER` is non-tied

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        rn = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.emp_id ORDER BY seq DESC)
    FROM yourTable t
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: @OctavianWR . . . If you are going to use window functions (which are unnecessary) then this is the better and clearer approach.

Answer (score -1):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.seq = (select max(t2.seq) from t t2 where t2.emp_id = t.emp_id);
```